# json error Bad JSON escape sequence

Tags: c#, json

I am working with json but i got an error Bad JSON escape sequence

```
    var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<test>(def);
public class test
    {
        public string test123 { get; set; }
    }
```

My json def is `"{\"test123 \": \"î'ï\u0014¹\u0019ö\\±ýŽ± \u0013Eú\", }"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you can use [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) for validate your JSON.Then you can use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) for creating correct class for your JSON.

Comment: it's didn't work with my json {"test": "JÅø\¦"¶
 ˜/éÆ™M¢b",}

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why you accepted this as an answer then.

Answer (score 16):

Please use 4 back slashes to print a single back slash in the resultant JSON string. Two slashes turns into one slash and escapes C#'s string only, to escape JSON, you will need another two. Or use can use the @ string for simplification.

```
"{\"test123 \": \"î'ï\u0014¹\u0019ö\\\\±ýŽ± \u0013Eú\", }"
```

Or

```
@"{""test123 "": ""î'ï\u0014¹\u0019ö\\±ýŽ± \u0013Eú"", }"
```

Comment: How do I use @ if I get the json as input?

Comment: @ayala You can use @ directly without the need for escaping.