# Error received Bad JSON escape sequence

Tags: c#, json, syntax-error

I'm currently testing an application but it's throwing a Bad JSON Escape Sequence at me, however I don't see the problem...

I'm probably overlooking something so a fresh pair of eyes might be useful.

```
messageContents = "{\"command\":\"cue\",\"channel\":1,\"uid\":\"aesd-deaf\",\"type\":\"standard\",\"waitforexecute\":true,\"duration\":0,\"scene\":[{\"name\":\"Scene1\",\"fields\":[{\"Quad1\":\"F:\\TestFolder\\mill.jpg\"}]}]}";
```

And the error I'm getting is

```
{"Bad JSON escape sequence: \\T. Path 'scene[0].fields[0].Quad1', line 1, position 150."}
```

Can anyone spot the mistake?
Thanks,
Kenneth

Comment: How do you process it?

Comment: cuezClass data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<cuezClass>(messageContents) as cuezClass;

Comment: JsonLint complains about the string `{"command":"cue","channel":1,"uid":"aesd-deaf","type":"standard","waitforexecute":true,"duration":0,"scene":[{"name":"Scene1","fields":[{"Quad1":"F:\TestFolder\mill.jpg"}]}]}` (which is your string) - there should be extra \ characters in the file path - \\ should be \\\\.

Comment: well, people here are pretty much impatient so I'll write here. \\ is interpreted as a single slash but produces problems like the one you experienced. look at this post for relevence: https://forums.asp.net/t/2119484.aspx?Problem+with+double+backslash+in+the+file+path+after+json+serialization+

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/41646878/993547.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Like the error says, the problem happens inside the array for the `fields` property:

```
[{\"Quad1\":\"F:\\TestFolder\\mill.jpg\"}]
```

Imagine what this looks like, once parsed:

```
[{"Quad1": "F:\TestFolder\mill.jpg"}]
```

The JSON parser doesn't recognize the escape sequence `\T`, which is not the same as `\t`.

To fix is simply double escape all the `\` characters. So that section would look like:

```
\"fields\": [{\"Quad1\":\"F:\\\\TestFolder\\\\mill.jpg\"}]
```

Comment: So...negative votes for a correct answer? At least, I hope it helped, Cainnech.

Comment: You are correct, that was the issue. I wasn't taking into consideration that the \ had to be double-escaped.